# MATLAB urlread Won't Work for Specific Webpage

Tags: matlab, web-scraping, urlread

I am attempting to scrape a webpage using the `urlread()` function in MATLAB, though I've run into a problem that I haven't seen before. When I run the code

`X = urlread('http://espn.go.com/mens-college-basketball/schedule/_/date/20141114');`

I get the error

`Error using urlreadwrite (line 92)
The server did not find a resource to match this request.`

`Error in urlread (line 36)
[s,status] = urlreadwrite(mfilename,catchErrors,url,varargin{:});`

When I attempt to visit the link on my browser (http://espn.go.com/mens-college-basketball/schedule/_/date/20141114), I have no problems accessing the page. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the site is blocking the default `MATLAB Rxxxxx` user-agent parameter in the http request.

Faking the user-agent seems to work around the limitation:

```
x = urlread('http://espn.go.com/mens-college-basketball/schedule/_/date/20141114', 'UserAgent', 'Mozilla/5.0');
```

Answer (score 0):

That didn't work for me, but this does.

```
URL = 'http://espn.go.com/mens-college-basketball/schedule/_/date/20141114';
str = urlread(URL,'Get',{'term','urlread'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I think r and Python are much better for web scraping exercises.

Here's an R script that works great.

```
library(rvest)
rawhtml <- read_html("http://espn.go.com/mens-college-basketball/schedule/_/date/20141114")
rvested <- rawhtml %>% 
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
    .[[1]]
```