# Garbled when using urlread in Matlab

Tags: matlab, urlread

When I was using *urlread* to scrape the website: http://www.trackdota.com, the returen is garbled.

Code:

```
url = 'http://www.trackdota.com'
urlread(url)
```

the return is something like:

```
      �Xms�6��_�:�|#��l��+�qҤә�M�n�ǣ�H��
 Z�$��}�/"eIuo���� ��.<ޏt薹`s���ޘ~�t"���.}��
```

even if I reset the charset:

```
url = 'http://www.trackdota.com'
urlread(url,'charset','UTF-8')
```

My OS is Windows 8 and the version of Matlab is 2013b.

Comment: Consulting the documentation of `urlread`: *If the server returns binary data, the string will contain garbage.*. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html... so what you're experiencing is probably due to this reason.

Comment: @rayryeng So it's impossible to read the text on this website?

Comment: I don't know. I'm only quoting what the documentation says. It may be giving off binary data. I can't tell you for sure.

Comment: @rayryeng OK, any way, thank you.

Comment: The documentation suggests to use [webread](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html) instead, have you tried that?

Comment: @Jørgen I know, but webread is only in Matlab 2015b.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the version you used. Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682063/matlab-urlread-wont-work-for-specific-webpage/33682983 , i.e. specifying the user-agent? I'm at home without a Matlab installation, so I cannot test this.